# Android Notification . How to Reopen Previous activity?

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Music.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(Music.this)
            .setContentTitle("Music PLayer")
            .setContentText("Subject")
            .setContentIntent(intent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setAutoCancel(true).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = 
      (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, n);
    super.onPause();
}
```

This is a media player and every time I click the home button it will go to the `onPause()`
and the music will still be playing and the `seekbar` still runs and every time my activity is on the `onPause()` it will open the notification and when I click the notification it will return me to my activity again.

The problem is that every time I click it, it starts a new activity and resets everything. What I want is for it to resume the last activity that was still running.

Comment: You need to read documentation carefully: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html & http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to play music using service .This should be a [binded service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) that will be started from another service and stopped on distroy() of Binding service